# One of my 3 monitors stopped working on Ubuntu (screen stopped working)

Tags: graphics, display

I have 3 monitors plugged into my RX 5600XT graphics card. All of them worked fine with my Ubuntu until last week when the first monitor stopped working on Ubuntu. I know it's not a hardware problem because they all work together on Windows and even Ubuntu recognizes all 3 of them.
What happens is that Ubuntu detects but keeps it turned off, always when I select the monitor. No matter what I do, it will always end up turned off. I turn it back on and apply the changes, then it goes back to turned off. If I disconnect one of the working monitors, the problematic one starts working (again reinforcing it's not a hardware issue).
[image]

Comment: This may be a graphics driver issue. Was the driver updated recently? If so, try going back to the previous version of the graphics driver.

Comment: I don't actually know if the driver was updated. I do install the daily updates provided by the software changes so it's possible that the graphics card driver might have been updated as well. Is it possible to check that?

Comment: Go to the folder `/var/log/apt/` and look for the file `history.log`. This will show you the history of the updates used by the apt command. Older logs are stored as compressed archives with file type `.gz`. These are similar to zip files and can be opened from the Files (AKA Nautilus) app.

Comment: Didn't work with the oldest kernel available.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause of the issue. For some reason, the Display settings window doesn't update the `~/.config/monitors.xml` when enabling the monitor, only for disabling. If you take a look into the file, there is a tag called `<disabled></disabled>`. It seems that the "Display settings" only adds the monitor to that list when you disable it, it doesn't remove when you enable.

So in order to fix the issue I edited that file and removed the monitor from that tag, then I logged out to end the session. When I logged back in it had all 3 monitors working.

This how the `<disabled></disabled>` tag was:

```
<disabled>
  <monitorspec>
    <connector>HDMI-A-0</connector>
    <vendor>GSM</vendor>
    <product>LG FULL HD</product>
    <serial>0x01010101</serial>
  </monitorspec>
</disabled>
```

This is how I left it to fix the issue:

```
<disabled>
</disabled>
```